# intel assembly difference between al and r8b

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel, cpu-registers

I am wondering what is the main difference between the AL and R8B
from what I understand AL means the 8 lowest bits of the RAX and R8B the 8 lowest bits of R8

But the final output of my program is not the same (it is actually not working AL when it is with R8B) but both seems to serve the same purpose.

Comment: What does your program look like?  Another difference between RAX and R8 is that RAX is used as the return value register.  So if you use AL you may be clobbering your return value.

Answer (score 2):

There are differences. Using `r8b` implies a REX.R or REX.B, and having any REX prefix at all means you can't use `ah`, `ch`, `dh` or `bh` in the same instruction (the encodings used for them will instead mean `spl`, `bpl`, `sil` and `dil` respectively). So for example, this is encodable:

```
add al, ah
```

But this is not encodable:

```
add r8b, ah
```

So they are not entirely interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

They are different registers. RAX can be "translated" as R0. So AL would be R0B. But for historical reasons the name is RAX and for the lower 8 bits it's AL.

Comment: Actually `rax` is `r0` not `r1`.

Comment: @Jester indeed - we start counting with 0 - thank you.